# How can I handle attributes in python?

Tags: python, arguments

I have to create a function, printObjects(attribute, option), which must print the objects based on a certain attribute. The attribute can take ints or strings as input. The option attribute is optional. How do I implement this for my class?

Comment: "The option attribute is optional"  what?!?!  I hope this means that the 2nd parameter of printObjects, which is named 'option', is not mandatory.  Otherwise i am very confused with the different uses of option/attribute.  Assuming you meant what i hope, what is option for?  and what does it default to?

Comment: *print* *the* *objects* *based* *on* *a* *certain* *attribute* what is this supposed to mean? :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like this, or perhaps it will be helpful at least:

```
def printObject(obj, attributes=()):
  for a in attributes:
     print getattr(obj, a)
```

Comment: **Never use something mutable as default argument.** (Unless you actually know how it works and *want* this behaviour; also, it won' resul tin any bugs *in this example* but it's better to point this out anyway) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: In this case it's fine, 'attributes' isn't written to.

Comment: This was the right way to do it. Thanks. Sorry about my ambiguity in the original question, but this guy got what I meant :)

Comment: @delnan, you are right that the the mutable argument is dangerous. It was to make the code easy to read, but I can use a tuple to achieve the same effect

Comment: @Trim: If this answer is correct for you, then accept it (use the tick to the left of the answer).